# Jenkins - ERROR: Reference path does not exist

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-cloud

I got an error message when I use sub-modules in Jenkins that are referencing bitbucket as source control system.

Windows Server 2012 R2
Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 2.73.1
Bitbucket: Private

The ssh key authentication is fine as I can download the data from the repositories separately without any errors but got the error when I specify the sub-module inside the job.

ERROR: Reference path does not exist: git@bitbucket.org:stuff/repo.git

Any idea guys?

output:

---

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Extra_new9
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Extra_new9 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:yes/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/dev^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/dev^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 879325c17c9d8043c95a03e954b85c5eb26fbee3 (refs/remotes/origin/dev)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git checkout -f 879325c17c9d8043c95a03e954b85c5eb26fbee3

Commit message: "yeeeey"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git remote # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule init # timeout=10

 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule sync # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10

 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule init # timeout=10
ERROR: Reference path does not exist: git@bitbucket.org:somethingelse/subrepo.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.*)\.url # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config --get submodule.subrepo.url # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git remote # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.subrepo.path # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule update --init --recursive --remote subrepo

ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes

FATAL: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule update --init --recursive --remote subrepo" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git submodule update --init --recursive --remote subrepo" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1097)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1193)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: sadly not yet. I will need to investigate this further.

Comment: Ok. I made it work on a test environment but not on my main project.

Comment: setting up the local environment using the ssh url seems to be working.

Comment: @Roland how did you "make it work"?

Comment: SOLVED!
Changing the forking on the sub repository has done the trick for me.
From: "Allow private forks" to "Allow forks"